# radarchart axis range

Tags: r, plot

I created a radar chart using the function of “radarchart” from the “fmsb” package in R software.

The matrix I am using is as follows:

```
x<-c(c(rep(4.5,7),c(rep(0,7)), 3.34, 3.28, 1.37, 1.12, 3.52, 4.07, 3.66));
a<-as.data.frame(matrix(x,nrow=3, ncol=7,byrow=T))
radarchart(a,axistype=4,seg=3,cglty=3,pty=32,cglcol=1,plwd=3,pcol=1,axislabcol=1)
```

I would like to show the range of `c(0,5)` on the axis instead of  `c(0,100)` or `c(0,1)`. 
I really appreciate it if any body can guide me.

Comment: What have you tried? It is really hard for me to understand what you want. Try showing the code you have tried, and then draw in what you want, and then post the image.

Comment: Your example does not work: `The data must be given as dataframe`.

Comment: @ Paul Hiemstra My example workes since I wrote "as.data.frame " a<-as.data.frame(matrix(x,nrow=3, ncol=7,byrow=T))

Comment: Note: _I_ wrote that, that was my edit a few minutes ago...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By using a rather quick tweak, `radarchart` now has an additional argument which allows you to manually specify the numbers on the axes:

```
require(fmsb)
x = c(rep(4.5,7),rep(0,7), 
      3.34, 3.28, 1.37, 1.12, 3.52, 4.07, 3.66)
a = as.data.frame(matrix(x,nrow=3, ncol=7,byrow=T))
radarchart(a, axistype = 4, seg = 3, cglty = 3, 
           pty = 32, cglcol = 1, plwd = 3, pcol = 1, axislabcol = 1,
           labels = seq(from = min(x), to = max(x), length = 4))
```

[image]

The updated source code, my additions are marked by comments:

```
radarchart = function (df, axistype = 0, seg = 4, pty = 16, pcol = 1:8, plty = 1:6, 
          plwd = 1, cglty = 3, cglwd = 1, cglcol = "navy", axislabcol = "blue", 
          title = "", maxmin = TRUE, na.itp = TRUE, labels = NULL, ...) 
{
  if (!is.data.frame(df)) {
    cat("The data must be given as dataframe.\n")
    return()
  }
  if ((n <- length(df)) < 3) 
    return()
  if (maxmin == FALSE) {
    dfmax <- apply(df, 2, max)
    dfmin <- apply(df, 2, min)
    df <- rbind(dfmax, dfmin, df)
  }
  plot(c(-1.2, 1.2), c(-1.2, 1.2), type = "n", frame.plot = FALSE, 
       axes = FALSE, xlab = "", ylab = "", main = title, asp = 1, 
       ...)
  theta <- seq(90, 450, length = n + 1) * pi/180
  theta <- theta[1:n]
  xx <- cos(theta)
  yy <- sin(theta)
  for (i in 0:seg) {
    polygon(xx * (i + 1)/(seg + 1), yy * (i + 1)/(seg + 1), 
            lty = cglty, lwd = cglwd, border = cglcol)
    if (axistype == 1 | axistype == 3) 
     ## Changes by me  
     if(is.null(labels)) labels = paste(i/seg * 100, 
                                         "(%)")
      text(-0.05, (i + 1)/(seg + 1), labels[i+1], col = axislabcol)
    if (axistype == 4 | axistype == 5) 
      ## Changes by me
      if(is.null(labels)) labels = sprintf("%3.2f", i/seg)
      text(-0.05, (i + 1)/(seg + 1), labels[i+1], 
           col = axislabcol)
  }
  arrows(xx/(seg + 1), yy/(seg + 1), xx * 1, yy * 1, lwd = cglwd, 
         lty = cglty, length = 0, col = cglcol)
  if (axistype == 2 | axistype == 3 | axistype == 5) {
    text(xx[1:n], yy[1:n], df[1, 1:n], col = axislabcol)
  }
  text(xx * 1.2, yy * 1.2, colnames(df))
  series <- length(df[[1]])
  if (length(pty) < (series - 2)) {
    ptys <- rep(pty, series - 2)
    pcols <- rep(pcol, series - 2)
    pltys <- rep(plty, series - 2)
    plwds <- rep(plwd, series - 2)
  }
  else {
    ptys <- pty
    pcols <- pcol
    pltys <- plty
    plwds <- plwd
  }
  for (i in 3:series) {
    xxs <- xx
    yys <- yy
    scale <- 1/(seg + 1) + (df[i, ] - df[2, ])/(df[1, ] - 
      df[2, ]) * seg/(seg + 1)
    if (sum(!is.na(df[i, ])) < 3) {
      cat(sprintf("[DATA NOT ENOUGH] at %d\n%g\n", i, df[i, 
                                                         ]))
    }
    else {
      for (j in 1:n) {
        if (is.na(df[i, j])) {
          if (na.itp) {
            left <- ifelse(j > 1, j - 1, n)
            while (is.na(df[i, left])) {
              left <- ifelse(left > 1, left - 1, n)
            }
            right <- ifelse(j < n, j + 1, 1)
            while (is.na(df[i, right])) {
              right <- ifelse(right < n, right + 1, 1)
            }
            xxleft <- xx[left] * (1/(seg + 1) + (df[i, 
                                                    left] - df[2, left])/(df[1, left] - df[2, 
                                                                                           left]) * seg/(seg + 1))
            yyleft <- yy[left] * (1/(seg + 1) + (df[i, 
                                                    left] - df[2, left])/(df[1, left] - df[2, 
                                                                                           left]) * seg/(seg + 1))
            xxright <- xx[right] * (1/(seg + 1) + (df[i, 
                                                      right] - df[2, right])/(df[1, right] - 
                                                        df[2, right]) * seg/(seg + 1))
            yyright <- yy[right] * (1/(seg + 1) + (df[i, 
                                                      right] - df[2, right])/(df[1, right] - 
                                                        df[2, right]) * seg/(seg + 1))
            if (xxleft > xxright) {
              xxtmp <- xxleft
              yytmp <- yyleft
              xxleft <- xxright
              yyleft <- yyright
              xxright <- xxtmp
              yyright <- yytmp
            }
            xxs[j] <- xx[j] * (yyleft * xxright - yyright * 
              xxleft)/(yy[j] * (xxright - xxleft) - xx[j] * 
              (yyright - yyleft))
            yys[j] <- (yy[j]/xx[j]) * xxs[j]
          }
          else {
            xxs[j] <- 0
            yys[j] <- 0
          }
        }
        else {
          xxs[j] <- xx[j] * (1/(seg + 1) + (df[i, j] - 
            df[2, j])/(df[1, j] - df[2, j]) * seg/(seg + 
            1))
          yys[j] <- yy[j] * (1/(seg + 1) + (df[i, j] - 
            df[2, j])/(df[1, j] - df[2, j]) * seg/(seg + 
            1))
        }
      }
      polygon(xxs, yys, lty = pltys[i - 2], lwd = plwds[i - 
        2], border = pcols[i - 2])
      points(xx * scale, yy * scale, pch = ptys[i - 2], 
             col = pcols[i - 2])
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer by rescaling chart axis as follows:

```
for(i in 0:seg) #seg=The number of segments
text(-0.05, (i + 1)/(seg + 1), sprintf("%3.2f", i/seg))
```

in my case,

```
radarchart(a,axistype="",seg=3,cglty=3,pty=32,cglcol=1,plwd=3,pcol=1,axislabcol=1,title="")
text(-0.05, (0:3 + 1)/4, sprintf("%3.2f", quantile(0:5,probs=c(0,0.33,0.67,1))),col = 1)
```

Comment: +1, you could always tweak the plot afterwards ofcourse :). My solution works directly on `radarchart`.

Answer (score 0):

Update for fmsb version 0.6.1:

**!! the `labels` parameter has changed to `caxislabels` !!**

The correct script to display the values instead of percentage on the x-axis is now:

```
require(fmsb)
x = c(rep(4.5,7),rep(0,7), 
      3.34, 3.28, 1.37, 1.12, 3.52, 4.07, 3.66)
a = as.data.frame(matrix(x,nrow=3, ncol=7,byrow=T))

windows()
radarchart(a, axistype = 4, seg = 3, cglty = 3, 
           pty = 32, cglcol = 1, plwd = 3, pcol = 1, axislabcol = 1,
           caxislabels = seq(from = min(x), to = max(x), length = 4))
```

[image]