# Adding Legends to a radarchart

Tags: r, graphics, plot, legend

By following this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12025943/radarchart-axis-range-r-language)

I have created a radar chart. Can anyone suggest me how to add a legend to this graph?

Comment: I'm sorry. It was an unwanted question by confusion. I appologize

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a generic legend to get you started. You can alter it to suit your particular needs:

```
legend(-2,0,
       legend=c("V1","V2"),
       pch=c(15,16),
       col=c("blue","red"),
       lty=c(1,2))
```

The first two arguments are the location of the legend, in terms of the plot's (x,y) coordinates. Check the help for more details on the various arguments to the `legend` function.

I think you're getting negative votes because you essentially asked others to do your work for you. In the future, try out a few things first to see if you can get at least a partial answer. Then, in your question, explain what you've tried and what, specifically, you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Thanks @eipi10. I'll follow your instructions next time.