# Why am I getting "plot.new has not been called yet" calling legend() after chartJSRadar()

Tags: r, legend, chart.js

The context here is the R Project for Statistical Computing

Consider the following code (from chartJSRadar documentation)

```
library(radar chart)
labs <- c("Communicator", "Data Wangler", "Programmer",
      "Technologist",  "Modeller", "Visualizer")

scores <- list(
  "Rich" = c(9, 7, 4, 5, 3, 7),
  "Andy" = c(7, 6, 6, 2, 6, 9),
  "Aimee" = c(6, 5, 8, 4, 7, 6)
)

chartJSRadar(scores = scores, labs = labs, maxScale = 10)
```

I want to put a legend on in using:

```
legend("topleft", c("Rich","Andy","Aimee"), cex=0.8, fill=colors)
```

But I get the following error:

```
Error in strwidth(legend, units = "user", cex = cex, font = text.font) : 
  plot.new has not been called yet
```

I've seen many other questions about this error message. Some of them was because legend coordinates were off the chart. Some others give a workaround but do not explain why the error occur.

My question is: why am I getting this error? It seems something fundamentally wrong like an incompatibility between legend() and chartJSRadar(), but I don't get it.

Please advise!

Comment: Here is one link where I can see a legend for your kind of plot:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23206354/legend-with-radarchart-in-loop

Comment: Thanks for your message. It does use fmsb instead of radarchart as suggested by Sowmya

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems `chartJSRadar` does not call a plot but shows an interactive plot in the viewer. Hence a plot is not called and you cannot use `legend()`. From the documentation for `chartJSRadar`, it does seem like there is a legend option for the radar plot, see http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#radar-chart-chart-options:

```
//String - A legend template
legendTemplate : "<ul class=\"<%=name.toLowerCase()%>-legend\"><% for (var i=0; i<datasets.length; i++){%><li><span style=\"background-color:<%=datasets[i].strokeColor%>\"></span><%if(datasets[i].label){%><%=datasets[i].label%><%}%></li><%}%></ul>"
```

This is JavaScript, which I have no expertise in, so unfortunately this is as far as I can help you.

Comment: "Hence a plot is not called and you cannot use legend()". This almost answer my question. Please help me to understand how it is in R. How was I supposed to know that the "interactive plot" is not a "regular plot"? Is it documented? Is it a concept I am missing? How many different types/categories of plots are there?

Comment: @Chocksmith Your plot opens up in a html document, where as most of the plots are plotted in R's own graphics device window.

Comment: I don't think you were supposed to know, except if you use RStudio, your plot is shown in the viewer pane since, as @SowmyaS.Manian states, it is an html-document. [Web content is shown in the viewer pane](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/202133558-Extending-RStudio-with-the-Viewer-Pane).

Answer (score 5):

If using R Studio make sure to run the entire chunk (not ctr + enter). I had a similar issue using igraph. I tried to attach the legend to the graph but had the same error message. Running the entire chunk worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `fmsb` package which has `radarchart()` function. You can plot the same for your data.

http://127.0.0.1:25882/library/fmsb/html/radarchart.html

I tried it in R and it works in R plot window. As I do not understand the radar chart data. You would definitely be able to do it with legend using `radarchart()` and `legend()`using package `fmsb`

Comment: link is broken. The correct one is: http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/fmsb/docs/radarchart